# Every derived table must have its own alias error mysql

Tags: mysql, alias

i'm running this query on mysql

```
SELECT dranken.naam, evenement.waardeBonnetjes as drankPrijs  
       SUM(drankAantal1) as drankAantal from( 
           SELECT consumpties.aantal as drankAantal1 FROM consumpties, 
                  drankencategorie, consumptiebezoeker 
           WHERE drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? and
                 drankencategorie.idDranken = consumptiebezoeker.idEventDrank 
                 and consumpties.idConsumptieBezoeker = consumptiebezoeker.id 
       ), 
       SUM(totaalAantalBonnetjes1) as totaalAantalBonnetjes from( 
           SELECT dranken.aantalBonnetjes as totaalAantalBonnetjes1 from dranken,        
           evenementdrank, drankencategorie 
           WHERE dranken.id = evenementdrank.idDrank 
           and evenementdrank.idEvent = ? and drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? 
       )
FROM 
       evenement 
WHERE evenement.id = ? and drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? 
      and dranken.id = drankencategorie.idDranken
```

It give the error:
Every derived table must have its own alias error

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
( 
           SELECT consumpties.aantal as drankAantal1 FROM consumpties, 
                  drankencategorie, consumptiebezoeker 
           WHERE drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? and
                 drankencategorie.idDranken = consumptiebezoeker.idEventDrank 
                 and consumpties.idConsumptieBezoeker = consumptiebezoeker.id 
       ) t1
```

each select beyond the 1st must have an alias (t1) or something that the compiler can reference/build from.

or full answer:

```
SELECT dranken.naam, evenement.waardeBonnetjes as drankPrijs  
       SUM(drankAantal1) as drankAantal from( 
           SELECT consumpties.aantal as drankAantal1 FROM consumpties, 
                  drankencategorie, consumptiebezoeker 
           WHERE drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? and
                 drankencategorie.idDranken = consumptiebezoeker.idEventDrank 
                 and consumpties.idConsumptieBezoeker = consumptiebezoeker.id 
       ) t1, 
       SUM(totaalAantalBonnetjes1) as totaalAantalBonnetjes from( 
           SELECT dranken.aantalBonnetjes as totaalAantalBonnetjes1 from dranken,        
           evenementdrank, drankencategorie 
           WHERE dranken.id = evenementdrank.idDrank 
           and evenementdrank.idEvent = ? and drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? 
       ) t2
FROM 
       evenement 
WHERE evenement.id = ? and drankencategorie.idCategorie = ? 
      and dranken.id = drankencategorie.idDranken
```